# How to update the custom field on Account based on custom field in event

Tags: trigger, event

How to update the custom field named as Current Command on Account Page. I want to insert the value from the Feedback(custom field) entered by customer. Event is the on process i want to show the latest one. I attach my Account page.[image]

My Event Page and Field[image] Details

Comment: what is the relationship here between event and account. because we copy value from parent to child and in this case account is parent.

Comment: Parent  and child relationships..... Event is like activity i need to track the activity and show it on the Accound page

Comment: you are trying to copy value from child to parent?

Comment: yes i need on show that value  Account page

Comment: How it change i need to update the current status of latest one... for example in image value "More Details needed" after that it will change to "Not Interest" means i need to show the "Not Interest"  to "Current Command"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to accomplish with process builder.

Setup - > Create -> Workflow & Approvals -> Process Builder

1) Choose "Event" object under "Choose Object and Specify When to Start the Process" section.

2) "Define Criteria for this Action Group" select "No criteria—just execute the actions!"

3) Under "Action Type" select "Update Records"

4) Under "Record Type" select "Select a record related to the Event" radio button and then "Account Id" which is without right Arrow.

5) "Criteria for Updating Records" select "No criteria—just update the records!"

6) Under "Set new field values for the records you update" select your account field. Choose Type as "Reference" and then under "Value Choose your Event field which needs to be copied.

Comment: Hi Team Apps, I get this error ,Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301O00000009Wcy. Contact your administrator for help. 

Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: ,In my scenario i have the account page and then another one is custom page. for example student details is the (Account) and depends department is my custom page.In department i have student name in vlookup value.In the event page i have the student name and Department No as vlookup value. I need to fetch the feedback value from the event page.whenever it changed i need to update in the current feedback on account page

Answer (score 0):

In your current scenario write trigger on event and on insert and update find parent Account and update the value of current Feedback(Account) With Feedback(Event). Nut this is not a good approach because one parent can have multiple child. And in this way they will overwrite the value.

Comment: Hi Tushar, I already write the trigger it does not update value.... My trigger is trigger change_feedback on Event  (after insert, after update)  {
     Set<String> accountSet = new Set<String>();     
     List<Event> event = [select Id,Whatid,FEEDBACK__C from Event where id in :trigger.newMap.keySet()];    List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();    Map<Id,String> accntValMap = new Map<Id,String>();

Comment: for(Event e : trigger.new){
         if(e.Status == 'Appointment') {  accIds.add(e.whatId);
        accntValMap.put(e.whatId,e.FEEDBACK__C);      }       }       List<Account> acctsToUpdate = [Select Id from Account where id in :accntValMap.keySet()];      for(Account acc : acctsToUpdate){
     acc.Feedback__c = accntValMap.get(acc.Id);   }
      update acctsToUpdate;}